# Read map data when you do not know the key and value in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux, reactive-programming

I have data as :

```
 data =     [
            { 
                "name": "James Angus", 
                "age" : "22", 
                "job": "Dentist" 
            },
            { 
                "name": "Milan Howen", 
                "age" : "36", 
                "job": "Truck Driver" 
            }   
        ];
```

I am reading this as present :-

```
const renderItems = this.state.data.map(function(item, i) {
       return <li key = {i} > {item.name} < /li> 
 }
```

Here i am giving the key to read i.e. item.name
So it reads all the name

But if i am not aware about key ... how should i iterate.

Means for all keys it should read the value without we specifying the key in reactjs.

I hope i am able to make my question clear .

Comment: you can do `console.log(item)` inside your map function and you'll know the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) API:

```js
let data = [{
  "name": "James Angus",
  "age": "22",
  "job": "Dentist"
}, {
  "name": "Milan Howen",
  "age": "36",
  "job": "Truck Driver"
}];

data.map((item, id) => {
  Object.keys(item).map((key) => {
    console.log(item[key])
  })
})
```

> You could also use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) API

```js
let data = [{
  "name": "James Angus",
  "age": "22",
  "job": "Dentist"
}, {
  "name": "Milan Howen",
  "age": "36",
  "job": "Truck Driver"
}];


data.map((item, id) => {
  console.log(Object.values(item))
})
```